# Match Month & Year in Row to Month & Year from another cell

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

Thanks in advance for any help!
I'm trying to use the below code to locate the month and year contained in a row of one worksheet that matches the month and year contained in a cell on a different worksheet. Then copy the matching column to a third worksheet. With the below, I'm receiving a "Type Mismatch" error on the line "If Month(Sheet6....". I'm not certain this is the most effective way to write this so I'm open to suggestions.

- Corrected the below to reflect the final working code

```
    Sub FindDate()

    'returns the month and year entered for the project review cycle

    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Integer
    Dim c As Long
    Dim d As Long

    a = Month(Sheet8.Cells(2, 3))

    b = Year(Sheet8.Cells(2, 3))


    'MsgBox a & "-" & b


    c = Sheet6.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlFormulas).Column

     For i = 1 To c

      If IsDate(Sheet6.Cells(1, i).Value) Then
        If Month(Sheet6.Cells(1, i)) = a And Year(Sheet6.Cells(1, i)) = b Then
         Sheet6.Columns(i).copy

         d = Sheet5.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
         SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlFormulas).Column
         Sheet5.Cells(1, d + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
         Sheet5.Cells(1, d + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
       End If
     End If
     Next i

    Application.CutCopyMode = False


    End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of `Sheet6.Cells(1, i)` at error?  Out of interest does `Sheet6.Cells(1, i).value` give the same?  Is sheet6 the correct sheet to?

Comment: You'll get a type mismatch if any of your values passed to Month/Year are not dates.

Comment: Ah, yes, some of the values being evaluated are not dates. Is there a workaround to say ignore a cell in the range if it's not a date?

Comment: I was able to get it to work by adding an additional "If" statement to the beginning which simply verifies whether the cell is a date or not. Thanks Tim Williams for the quick identification of my problem.